# electrostatics and elecrtic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

two opposite charges are placed and thee electric lines of forces are drawn if the angle made by the tangent at the initial point of one charge is 'a'then find the angle made by the line of force that ends at the other charge.[image: as shown in the figure charges don't ave equal magnitude. we have to find 'b']

Comment: this is not a homework site. Look at the guidelines for submitting homework type questions http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: http://se.u.94y.info for a list of potentially helpful resources

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the concept of solid angle and equate the two fluxes then find any angle you want to find...